# Сложение двух Классов

Tags: python, классы

кто то может подсказать, я так понимаю, нужно использовать метод *add*_ для слияние двух классов, вот и задача состоит в том, что, получается "AirCar" Скорость и Длина которого будут равны среднему между атрибутами Car и Plane которые я сложил.
вот, что мой код.

```
class Car:
    average_speed = 60
    average_lenght = 5
    cars = []
 
    def __init__(self, model, speed=average_speed, length=average_lenght):
        self.model = model
        self.speed = speed
        self.length = length
 
 
class AirPlane(Car):
    average_speed = 300
    average_lenght = 10
    Plane = []
 
    def magic(self):
        super(Car, self).__init__()
 
 
class AirCar(Car, AirPlane):
    def __add__(self, other):
        if self.cars:
            self.average_speed = sum([car.speed for car in self.cars]) / len(self.cars)
            self.average_lenght = sum([AirPlane.lenght for AirPlane in self.Plane]) / len(self.Plane)
            self.Aircar.append(self)
```

Comment: *btw: `lenght` → `length`, классическая опечатка)

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 2):

Я немного упростил ваш пример, надеюсь суть вы поймёте. В нём я показываю Вам как создавать объекты из классов, а после передавать их в класс.
Можно конечно делать валидацию на класс, я сделал на атрибут.

```
class Car:
    average_speed = 17


class AirPlane:
    average_speed = 600


class AirCar:
    total_speed: int 

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self._add(*args)
        print(self.total_speed)

    def _add(self, *args):
        self.total_speed = sum([cls.average_speed for cls in args if hasattr(cls, 'average_speed')]) / len(args)

car = Car()
plain = AirPlane()
c = AirCar(car,plain)

# 308.5
```

Comment: Думаю, в `AirCar` может только один `Car` и один `AirPlan` передаваться, поэтому в конструкторе сразу завести параметры под них. Тогда не будет нужды в ненужном цикле и проверках :)

Comment: Я вам показал пример, как это делать, дальше сами решайте как адаптировать этот код. Сейчас код универсален, и возьмёт сколько угодно машин и самолетов.

Comment: Не мне показывали, а автору вопроса ;)

Comment: ой))) ну бывает

Comment: задача заключалась в том, чтобы показать вам, как передавать объекты в класс.
это что бесплатная биржа фриланса?